# Is there an open source tainting tool?

Tags: java, open-source, taint

is there an open source tainting tool? I am trying to analyze a Java project and it's java source code. Therefore I can see where and which purpose are parameters used for. For instance, is it used in an if statement or is it assigned to another variable etc.

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard this term used in the context of Java ...

Comment: Is there an alternative term for the thing that I am looking, if there is it will be very helpful.

Comment: It is called [Taint Checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking)

Comment: @Ekin - the term is fine.  I was just remarking about the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).

Comment: Checker Framework just as I wanted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ekin: Eh? you wanted to see where a parameter is "used (for)".  A type checker doesn't show you *where*; it only checks that the type (of something) has a certain property.  Checker Framework appears to the do the latter (based on a breif look); how specifically does it do the former?

Comment: The link in the answer is dead. Here is the updated link: http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Modern java IDEs provide  such information.  IMHO, best one  is IntelliJ IDEA , but comemrcial license will cost you about 130$  (there is free community  edition 
wuth somehow reduced functionality with source code published, or 30 day  free trial 
of full version)

Eclipse and netbean also provide similar functionality, but are not as good. 
( IMHO of course )

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general purpose tool to track how a an arbitrary variable is used, or the source of values that feed into a variable, what you want is a [program slicer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing). (Tainting is a special case, where one only wants to slice on certain inputs, usually from a source outside the program).

There is one called [Indus](http://indus.projects.cis.ksu.edu/).  I've never used it, and I don't know its status.

Comment: To be more specific, I need to check the parameters if they are validated or not, and I don't know that a program slicer will help that part. By the way Checker does give the location of where the parameter has been used (maybe not the plugin version but surely show it on command line).

Comment: Don't you need to know where the Parameter(s) were used, and anything that is *indirectly* affected by the parameters?

Comment: Actually I do need know. However, a line number is not sufficient, it would be better if I also see what is going on (For example, an explanation,description, etc.)